# How do I import/convert VHS videos to DVD?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, hardware

Can somebody recommend me hardware and software to import VHS Videos to DVD's?

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of Linux is that there are many ways to do something.  Here is a basic solution:

Hardware

- Hauppague PVR-150 - PCI card providing MPEG capture in S-Video, Composite, and NTSC broadcast
- VCR
- Cables to connect VCR to PVR-150

Software

The software side seems a bit trickier.  I use MythTv for my capturing, but it's sort of like using a blow-torch to solder a resistor on a circuit board -- it can be done, but it's really not the right tool. :-)

VLC is probably your best best for what you want to do.  It can stream data from the PVR-150 to a file.  You will want to have a look at [this page on capturing with the PVR-150](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=55754) to understand how to choose the input source on the PVR-150.

Comment: Here's another tutorial about using using VLC with a PVR-150: http://thelinuxcurmudgeon.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-hauppauge-pvr-150250350500-tv.html